# Laravel Ajax controller set URL for set image

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

my html code is like this

```
@foreach($galleries as $photo)
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="single-galleries-sub-img">
            <div class="galleries-sub-img">
                <div class="testimonial-img"
                     style="background-image: url({{ asset('img/galleries/gallery-images/'.$photo->image) }})">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="galleries-sub-img-hvr">
                <a href="{{asset('img/galleries/gallery-images/'.$photo->image)}}"
                   data-lightbox="image-4"><i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- // End Single galleries sub image -->
@endforeach
```

in controller

```
foreach ($data as $row){
    $output.='<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="single-galleries-sub-img">
                <div class="galleries-sub-img">
                    <div class="testimonial-img"
                         style="background-image: '.    URL HERE    .'">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="galleries-sub-img-hvr">
                    <a href="'.    URL HERE    .'"
                       data-lightbox="image-4"><i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
}
```

Now my question is how can I set asset in href `.    URL Here   .` part and in style background image which can give me the same output like HTML when I fetch html code from controller Via AJAX. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **url** helper may be used to generate URLs for your image or requests. The generated URL will automatically use the scheme (HTTP or HTTPS) and host from the current request:

if this is your parent dir image path is: **img/galleries/gallery-images/**

```
foreach ($data as $row){
     $output.='<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="single-galleries-sub-img">
            <div class="galleries-sub-img">
                <div class="testimonial-img"
                     style="background-image: '.url("img/galleries/gallery-images/".$row->image).'">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="galleries-sub-img-hvr">
                <a href="'.url("img/galleries/gallery-images/".$row->image).'"
                   data-lightbox="image-4"><i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls